# Service Bus Retry logic: prefer queue retry or implement Polly?

Tags: c#, azureservicebus, polly, retry-logic

I have implemented a Service Bus queue listener that works very nicely. Thinking about possible failures, I have to choose between using the queue retry logic and implementing my own logic using Polly. My instinct is to use Polly for finer control over exponential backoff and differentiating between "showstopper" and "ignorable" failures, but a colleague prefers using the service bus retry logic. In my opinion queue retry logic will most likely keep failing until it puts everything on the dead letter queue, this increasing our maintenance burden in monitoring and remediating the dlq.

Have I considered everything? What are general guidelines in choosing how to implement queue retry logic?

Comment: Have you seen this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-exceptions and this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/retry-service-specific#service-bus?

Comment: Yes, I have seen that thanks. My understanding is that this retry will put messages back on the queue and then eventually the dlq for any exception. I am wondering of it is better to use Polly  to distinguish between exception types and use fallbacks, or to put messages back on the queue and rely on the queue for retries.

Comment: I may be wrong here but I think you will see the same behavior with polly as well as the retry logic is implemented on the client side.

Comment: One of the important things maybe the Max message size of the service bus is 256KB (Basic tier) and max 1024KB(Premium one). In Polly you don't have any limits as it's just a library and not the communication type of thing.